# Bad access on UITapGestureRecognizer

Tags: ios, uiview, uitapgesturerecognizer

I'm trying to add an UITapGestureRecognizer on my UIView. This is a part of the code of my UIViewController.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.

    // Create and initialize a tap gesture
    UITapGestureRecognizer *tapRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(respondToTapGesture:)];

    // Specify that the gesture must be a single tap
    tapRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;

    // Add the tap gesture recognizer to the view
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:tapRecognizer];

}

-(void) respondToTapGesture:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)gr {
    NSLog(@"It's working !");
}
```

The problem is that when I tap on the view, I have this message :

```
0x396e25d0:  ldr    r3, [r4, #8]      < Thread 1 : EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x8)
```

Does anyone has an idea ?

Comment: Sorry, I've edit the post. "It's respondToTapGesture:" and "address=0x8"

Comment: What if you change method argument type to id:  respondToTapGesture:(id)gr

Comment: Try changing `-(void) respondToTapGesture:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)gr` to `-(void) respondToTapGesture:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gr`.  (remove Tap)  This is how I set up a @selector for tap gestures.  Other than that I don't see anything wrong with your code.

Comment: You should enable exceptions breakpoints and check the line that is rising the exception.

Comment: I've tried to replace "UITapGestureRecognizer" by "UIGestureRecognizer" and "id" but it doesn't solve the problem. It only changes the address in my Bad Access message.

Comment: I've also enabled exceptions breakpoints but it didn't caught any.

Comment: After activating the Zombie mode, this is what comes out : 2013-05-17 11:48:12.479 Pariscope[2963:907] *** -[PSCinemaTablePopupGridCell respondToTapGesture:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x1d1daac0

Answer (score 0):

One of the possibilities of this error is if you are doing this on a modal view or something like that and it has already deallocced. Be sure to remove the gesture recognizer from self.view.window before going back/dismissing the viewcontroller that has the uiGestureRecognizer.

Has something to do with allocation or delegate methods!